# Python CSV: Unable to upload file. Index Error("String index out of range")

Tags: python, django, csv

I am trying to import a file using Python: I understand why I've got this error but don't manage to correct it. The code tries to access a blank line and return an out of range error message. How could I correct this?

```
file_data = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")     
print("1")
lines = file_data.split("\n")
#loop over the lines and save them in db. If error , store as string and then display
for line in lines:
    if not line:
        continue
    line = line.strip()     
    print(line)      
    # following line may not be used, as line is a String, just access as an array
    #b = line.split()
    print(line[0]) 
    print("2")
    fields = line.split(",")
    data_dict = {}
    data_dict["project_name"] = fields[0]
```

Comment: Why not use the csv library for this? Also, please share the entire error message.

Comment: I am learning django and just followed a tutorial.I am now using a ForeignKey model located on a different app in my project and cannot import the csv file at all now. what should I replace the field in my csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if the line is empty with

```
if not line:
    continue
```

And after that you strip it

```
line = line.strip()
```

But when you strip it, the line can become empty, which you don't check for.

Fix the order of those lines, so you have:

```
line = line.strip()
if not line:
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks, it`s sorted now.

Comment: Is there any reason in my code why it imports only the 1st line?